# Inside do while loop, I want to execute specific code for 3 times till condition satisfy for every 1 min in c#

Tags: c#, multithreading, timer, do-while

I want to execute a function 'post mail' for every 1 min till his flag get true for 3 times only in c#.
basically I want to retry function for 3 times every 1 min when flag is false
Plz give me the solution for this

```
do
{
    isSuccess = PostMailThroughSMTP
                .postMail(objSmtpClient.SmtpClient, objBuildMail.MailMsg);
    Thread.Sleep(1000);
}
while (isSuccess != true);
```

Comment: `Thread.Sleep` is not a great way to schedule actions. What kind of application are you developing? Windows Forms? Console App?

Comment: @TheodorZoulias Console app

Comment: In that case `Thread.Sleep` is OK-ish.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try this using a down counter:

```
int count = 3;
do
{
  isSuccess = PostMailThroughSMTP
              .postMail(objSmtpClient.SmtpClient, objBuildMail.MailMsg);
  Thread.Sleep(1000);
}
while ( isSuccess != true && --count >= 1 );
```

Answer (score 0):

Timers is a way to perform functions on a Interval let say every minute. In the Elapsed event you can put a Method with a for loop that performs the PostMailThroughSMTP three times or less when isSuccess is true.

If its used in a multi-threaded way, then don't use Thread.Sleep(x) but use  Thread.CurrentThread.Join(x) because thats not blocking.

Answer (score 0):

You current code corrected

```
bool isSuccess = false;

// for is more readable than while in the context
for (int attempt = 0; attempt < 3; ++attempt) {
  isSuccess = PostMailThroughSMTP.postMail(objSmtpClient.SmtpClient, objBuildMail.MailMsg); 

  // If we succeeded, we don't have to wait a minute
  if (isSuccess)
    break;

  // Every minute - 60 seconds - 60000 milliseconds
  Thread.Sleep(60000);  
}

...

if (isSuccess) {
  // eMail has been posted
} 
else {
  // eMail has NOT been posted 
}
```